# LU decomposition python with vector pivot

Tags: python, scipy, lapack

The LU decomposition function provided by scipy returns a permutation matrix **P**

```
P,L,U = scipy.linalg.lu(A)
```

Where **A** is a rectangular matrix. However the size of my problem do not allow to store **P** (even temporary) due to its size, I really need a function that computes a permutation vector (like `[L,U,P] = lu(A,'vector')` in Matlab). I found a lapack function

```
LU,p,info = scipy.linalg.lapack.dgetrf(A)
```

which seems to return a vector **p** but I learned this latter is not an actual permutation vector since it contains twice the same value (https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-math-kernel-library/topic/780655). I am thus looking for another function (which may be from another library) to perform this LU decomposition with pivoting. Since the computation time is also very important, I don't think implementing the decomposition myself will be efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a pivot vector, which is a standard LAPACK return. So you'll need to convert it into whatever other form you want yourself (and this is much easier then reimplementing the factorization).